# DiscordJS fetching a Role's ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I am expereiencing a problem with my Discord Bot. What id does, it creates a Channel on Command and Assigns the Specific Role the Permission "VIEW_CHANNEL". Now the problem is, that I need to fetch the id of the Role. I have tried this (Code below) but it doesn't work.

`let admin = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "LuisChatAdmin").id;`

EDIT: Here is the Error. I'm sorry I forgot to attach it.

`(node:11956) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role. at Function.resolve (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Stuff\Scheiße die sich verpissen soll\LuisChat\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\PermissionOverwrites.js:177:28) at C:\Users\User\Desktop\Stuff\Scheiße die sich verpissen soll\LuisChat\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildChannelManager.js:109:81 at Array.map (<anonymous>) at GuildChannelManager.create (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Stuff\Scheiße die sich verpissen soll\LuisChat\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildChannelManager.js:109:51) at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Stuff\Scheiße die sich verpissen soll\LuisChat\bot.js:230:34) at Client.emit (events.js:333:22) at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Stuff\Scheiße die sich verpissen soll\LuisChat\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14) at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Stuff\Scheiße die sich verpissen soll\LuisChat\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32) at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Stuff\Scheiße die sich verpissen soll\LuisChat\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31) at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Stuff\Scheiße die sich verpissen soll\LuisChat\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)`

EDIT 2: Here is the entire Code:

`client.on('message', message => { if (message.content === "!setup") { if (message.channel.type === "text") { let admin = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "LuisChatAdmin").id; let bot = "752206832843620525"; if (message.guild.member(message.author).hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) { message.delete(); if (message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "LuisChatBypass")) { message.channel.send({ embed: { color: 15158332, author: { }, title: "Fehler", description: "Die Rollen existieren bereits.", }}) } else { message.guild.roles.create({ data: { name: "LuisChat Bypass", color: 'GREEN', } }) message.guild.roles.create({ data: { name: 'LuisChat Admin', color: 'RED', } }); message.guild.channels.create('luischat', { type: 'category', permissionOverwrites: [ { id: bot, allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'], }, { id: admin, allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'], },   { id: message.guild.id, deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'], } ] }) } } } } })`

Comment: "*It doesn't work*" How do you know this? Did you observe any errors? If so, why haven't you provided them here?

Comment: Judging by the error, that line is not the problem. The problem is that you set up the channel permissions wrong. Please provide that code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if(message.member.roles.cache.some(r=>["USER ROL"].includes(r.name)) ) {
    message.channel.send('MESSAGE')
} else {
    message.channel.send('u can't use because you don´t have permissions')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. That worked for me.